# Unexpected supervisor processes limitation

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord, beanstalkd

I’m using Beanstalkd queues in Laravel, controlled by Supervisord.

- Laravel v7.30.6
- Beanstalkd v1.10
- Supervisord v3.3.1
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (125G RAM)
- PHP 7.4

I have 19 tubes (queues) and around 1000 processes in total.

When I run supervisor in Systemd mode (`service supervisor start`) I face with some processes limitation. Supervisor runs only around 360 processes in total in some tubes, rest of tubes waits and doesn’t run processes at all.

[beanstalk console example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUAHn.png)

But when I run supervisor from command line from root (`/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`) all processes in all tubes runs normally.

So, **why I have limitations in Systemd mode?**

P.S.: and of course I know about system ulimit, and I have increased limits for root and for user owned tubes processes.

> ulimit -Hu: 655350

> ulimit -Su: 655350

Answer (score 0):

supervisord requires `minfds` parameter to increase open files limit for beanstalkd processes

make sure this is set

```
cat /etc/supervisord.conf
[supervisors]
...
minfds=1024;
```